# How to display full author details from BibTeX in ConTeXt?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, context

Using the following code, `\cite[author][lucas2004]` will print the authors' last names, e.g. "Lucas, Zeigler, and Kondrashov".

```
\usebtxdataset[default][/home/username/external.bib]

\setupbtx[dataset=default]
\usebtxdefinitions[apa]

\starttext
    \input knuth
    \cite[author][lucas2004]
    \placelistofpublications
\stoptext
```

I need to display the authors' names in other ways in the document:

- First Middle Last: John C. Smith, Peter K. Falk, and Robert H. White
- Last, First Middle: Smith, John C., Falk, Peter K., and White, Robert H
- With "el al." if there are more than three names: John C. Smith et al.
- Smith, John C. et al.

Is there a way to retrieve the author's names in these formats, from BibTeX using the `\cite` command in ConTeXt?

Comment: If `biblatex` is the package you used, then you can use the `maxnames` option to get what you want.

Comment: @M.Logic That's a LaTeX thing ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change option the `authorconversion=` to one of the following: `normal, normalshort, normalinverted, invertedshort, short`
(See Table 6.3 in the [publications manual](https://pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/mkiv-publications.pdf))

The options for *et al.* are controlled with: `etallimit=` and `etaldisplay=`

```
\usebtxdataset[default][mkiv-publications.bib]

\usebtxdefinitions[apa]
\setupbtx[dataset=default]

\setupbtx
    [apa:list:author]
    [authorconversion={normal},
     etallimit=]
\setupbtx
    [apa:cite:author]
    [authorconversion={normal},
     etallimit=3,
     etaldisplay=1]

\starttext
    Cite the article: \cite[author][article]
    Cite another way: \cite[alternative=author, authorconversion=inverted][article]
    \placelistofpublications
\stoptext
```

[image]